# Not getting proper data in php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

table: request

```
id          friend_id           candidate_id
==          ==============      ==============
1           20180928115958      20180925112428

2           20181008181142      20180925112428

3           20180928115958      20181008181142

4           20181010181207      20180928115958

5           20181008181142      20181010181207

6           20181010181207      20180925112428
```

Query

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['candidate_id']=20181010181207;

    $sql_ac = mysqli_query($con,"select friend_id,candidate_id from request where candidate_id='".$_SESSION['candidate_id']."' or friend_id='".$_SESSION['candidate_id']."'");
    while($row_ac = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_ac))
    {
        if($row_ac['friend_id']==$_SESSION['candidate_id'] && $row_ac['candidate_id']==$_SESSION['candidate_id'])
        {
            echo "";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $row_ac['friend_id']."<br/><br/>";
            echo $row_ac['candidate_id']."<br/><br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Unexpected  output:

```
20181010181207

20180928115958

20181008181142

20181010181207

20181010181207

20180925112428
```

Expected Output

```
20180928115958

20181008181142

20180925112428
```

In this code I have table `request` which have two key field i.e. `friend_id` and `candidate_id`. Now, I `$_SESSION['candidate_id']='20181010181207'`. So, How can I get expected output as I have mention above? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Still it showing `20181010181207

20180928115958

20181010181207

20180925112428` @MickaelLeger

Comment: It is doing exactly what you're asking it to do. It is returning 3 rows which match _candidate_ or _friend_. Then, for each one of those rows, you're outputting both the candidate ID and also the friend ID. Maybe, if you tell us what you're trying to do we could help.

Comment: Do you want to output `friend_id` when `candidate_id` matches and vice versa when `friend_id` matches?

Comment: have two ifs: `if(($row_ac['friend_id'] != $_SESSION['candidate_id'] { echo $row_ac['friend_id'] }` - same for conadidate_id

Comment: I want if this id `20181010181207` present in both `friend_id` and `candidate_id`. it will not show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
while($row_ac = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_ac))
{
    if($row_ac['friend_id'] != $_SESSION['candidate_id']
        echo $row_ac['friend_id']."<br/><br/>";
    }
    if($row_ac['candidate_id'] != $_SESSION['candidate_id']
        echo $row_ac['candidate_id']."<br/><br/>";
    }
}
```

This will display the values, that are *not* the same as the 'input', in other words remove the `20181010181207` entries.

Or as a oneliner:

```
echo $row_ac['candidate_id']==$_SESSION['candidate_id'] ? $row_ac['friend_id] : $row_ac['candidate_id'];
```

Comment: exactly I need this. Thanks @Jeff

Comment: You are welcome! There might be a better way in achieving this already on sql level. But it's hard to tell if it would fit your needs.

Comment: See @MickaelLeger s answer for a sql version!

Answer (score 1):

Your request is :

```
select 
  friend_id,
  candidate_id
from request 
where candidate_id=:candidate_id or friend_id=:candidate_id
```

So it's normal that you will return ALL row where `:candidate_id` is in column `friend_id` or `candidate_id` :

```
4           20181010181207      20180928115958

5           20181008181142      20181010181207

6           20181010181207      20180925112428
```

Now what you want is :

```
20180928115958 // this is candidate_id of row 4

20181008181142 // this is friend_id of row 5

20180925112428 // this is candidate_id of row 6
```

If you only want the value of the column "XXX_id" that is not equal to `:candidate_id`, try this :

```
select 
  IF(friend_id = :candidate_id, '', friend_id) as friend_id,
  IF(candidate_id = :candidate_id, '', candidate_id) as candidate_id
from request 
where candidate_id=:candidate_id or friend_id=:candidate_id
```

This way you will return empty value for column that match your `:candidate_id`.

Now just add a test before displaying it to avoid empty row :

```
if (!empty($row_ac['friend_id'])
    echo $row_ac['friend_id']."<br/><br/>";
if (!empty($row_ac['candidate_id'])
    echo $row_ac['candidate_id']."<br/><br/>";
```

---

You can do this too :

```
select 
  IF(friend_id = :candidate_id, candidate_id, friend_id) as result_id
from request 
where candidate_id=:candidate_id or friend_id=:candidate_id
```

This way you will return only ONE result : the one that is not equal to `:candidate_id`.

Then just do `echo $row_ac['result_id']."<br/><br/>";` to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

try this one

i hope it will working

```
if($row_ac['friend_id']==$_SESSION['candidate_id']){
    echo $row_ac['candidate_id']."<br/><br/>";
else{
    echo $row_ac['friend_id']."<br/><br/>";
}
```

Because `And` condition always false in your case and else part will execute so try with `if else` condition and check